# MVC with properties not mapped to the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model

I'm creating a view with a drop list and some other fields that will update a database. In the model there are properties that map to the database and some properties that are used for the dropdownlistfor. The unmapped properties throws an exception. Is there a good way to exclude the drop list properties from being mapped? I tried putting them in a separate class in the model and that didn't work.

The model:

```
[Table("cardata")]//Links the external table to this model object
public class Cardata
{
    //Maps to the database
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int dealerID { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public int numCyl { get; set; }
    public double weight { get; set; }


    // UNMAPPED Used for a drop list of car names
    public string carModel { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> carList
    {
        get
        {
            cartableContext ctc = new cartableContext();

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> retVal = ctc.cardata.GroupBy(c => c.model).Select(cl => cl.FirstOrDefault()).Select(cars => new SelectListItem { Value = cars.id.ToString(), Text = cars.model.ToString() });
            return retVal;
        }
        set { }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Bad practice (as is having database access code in a property)! You should be creating a view model that includes properties for view specific elements such as `SelectList`s. You can use tools such as [automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map you data model properties to your view model properties. Alternatively you can add the `SelectList` to ViewBag.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use [NotMapped]?

```
[NotMapped]
public string carModel { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> carList{...}
```